# In slim-select multi-select JQuery plugin how to set our custom values or id and fetch them and compare with other select options to disable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using slim-select [plugin]: https://www.cssscript.com/multi-select-dropdown-component-javascript-slim-select/ in my custom form in php wordpress template.

The is form option code where data comes from json file:

```
<select id="ddl5" name="per" class="dropd per gry">
        <option value="">Per</option>
            <?php
            $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = false;
            $output_s = file_get_contents('https://www.mywebsite.com/fee.json');
            $array_s = json_decode($output_s, true);
            $count = count( $array_s );
            for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ )
            {
  echo "<option value='".$array_s[$i]['id']."'>".$array_s[$i]['uom_name']."</option>";
            }?> </select>
```

Multi select js:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.26.0/slimselect.min.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.26.0/slimselect.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ss-multi-selected").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('.multiDDL').css("max-height", "inherit");
  });
});

    const my_MSD_object = new SlimSelect({
        select: '#ddl1-o',
        closeOnSelect: false,
    });

    var my_MSD_object2 = new SlimSelect({
        select: '#ddl1-bo',
        closeOnSelect: false,
    });

</script>
```

Now multi select works fine but here it creates select options in div's and has random values where as I need values from json file so that i can compare with other select option to disable the option

Multi select plugin creates this when used:

```
 <div class="ss-list">
      <div class="ss-option" data-id="45063549">Other Services</div>
      <div class="ss-option ss-disabled ss-option-selected" data-id="74143280">Director</div>
      <div class="ss-option" data-id="94288375">Cinematographer</div>
    </div>
```

And the default select value that is coming from simple php is hidden by plugin in front end :

```
<select id="ddl1-o" class="service gry" name="service" multiple="" tabindex="-1" data-ssid="ss-89838" style="display: none;">
        <option value="">Other Services</option>
        <option value="e7f18df3-3a9e-486f-ac8e-a8bf1d63dd51" id="service0">Director</option>. 
        <option value="02fbf950-30bc-44fc-adb2-696dde388cf3" id="service1">Cinematographer</option>
```

I need these above values Ex:02fbf950-30bc-44fc-adb2-696dde388cf3 in my multi select options as data-id or simple id that Jquery is creating and want to fetch those values, so that i can compare with other select option that has the same values coming from json file.

As one is primary services and another Other service, hence if one option selected in 1select should be disable in 2select.

Please let me know how I can write the JS/Query to do so as I find it tricky.

Answer (score 0):

By **showing and hiding** the original select (not the wrapper div from slimselect plugin), you could effectively update the wrapper select to the current state of the original select.